# I am a bit confused about deployment of cloud services, and particular whether just code can be replaced

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

Just getting used to VS2012 publishing of Cloud Services. At present I have a one instance webrole which contains a MVC3 application. I can publish it to Azure without issue, and it creates the Cloud Service>Web Role>VMs. Fine. Takes a little while.

However when I do a little code change how can I migrate just this code change without replacing all the VMs that implement the WebRole etc.

It seems that Code and infrastructure are inseparable, or have I misunderstood. Is there a way to just update the code bit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you roll out an update, you upload an entire package containing not only your code files, but also the configuration for the VM, such as # of instances, ports to open on the firewall, local resources to allocate, etc.  These configuration settings are part of the code package - so there is more going on than just updating code files.

However, there are a couple of methods you can use to have more granular control over updates.

1. Use [**Web Deploy**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/micham/archive/2011/04/07/how-to-update-web-application-directly-to-windows-azure-web-role-without-redeploying-azure-package.aspx).  One thing to keep in mind, is that any automatic service updates will restore your website to the last fully-deployed package, which may not be as up-to-date.  You would only want to use this in staging, then do a full package update for production rollout.
2. Use an [**Azure Web Site**](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-deploy/) instead, which allows continuous integration with your source control provider, and direct updates to the code.
3. Use an [**Iaas VM**](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/solutions/infrastructure/?WT.mc_id=azurebg_us_sem_google_br_solutions_nontest_infrastructure&WT.srch=1) instead.  These are basically the same as running your own custom server in the Azure cloud, and you have full control over the OS.  However, you also have full responsibility for keeping the OS updated and secure.
4. You can also [**enable RDP**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg443832.aspx) to your Azure Web Role VM's.  You will find all your code files there and IIS, but I wouldn't recommend updating your code this way for the same reasons listed in #1.

Comment: Thanks, very comprehensive. So basically use publish. I actually use WAWS for 90% of the web application and find it excellent. However we have some 3rd party PDF components which require Full trust and thus they have to run in a cloud service.

Comment: @SamJolly: Yes. I feel your pain with the 10-15 minutes it takes to update Azure services.  I've personally made heavy use of the Azure Emulator for more rapid testing cycles.  Also, I would recommend building your website so it works both on Azure and off Azure, so you can publish to a development/staging server prior to doing your Azure integration testing.

Comment: Ah the emulator. Yes I am using it, but I have found that the MVC code can run far more slowly through the emulator than on its own. OK emulators run more slowly, but it does seem pretty slow and I am running a 16GB I7 laptop. I did try debugging the MVC project by right clicking on the project, selecting "debugging" and then "start instance", however this still seemed pretty slow.

Comment: @SamJolly: Are you using Azure for your database even when debugging?  That would make it really slow.  If you want to have a test environment, it should be completely separate from Azure, including databases, files, etc.  I have a similar spec computer (16GB i5-3470), and I use emulator with a local SQL Express install on an SSD.  I find it to be extremely fast compared to the production environment.

Comment: I have done both, so will check :) However the gist I am getting from you is that running through the emulator should be pretty fast if you have got the setup correct, and certainly debugging against the MVC Project should be fine.

Comment: I did hear a rumour that one can use TFS against cloud services, so whether this will provide more granularity while protecting the code from overwrites, from older versions, after service packs.

Answer (score 2):

The code and infrastructure, in a cloud service, are actually separate. All you upload is a deployment package containing *just your code and supporting libraries / files*. You don't upload a vhd. Azure provides that for you, spinning up a vhd, and then accessing your code on a file folder on that vhd. Same process happens each time you scale out to more instances.

when you make a code change, you build a new deployment package and deploy that. If you do it as an in-place update (vs delete+redeploy), each role is updated on each instance (when you have multiple instances of a role, they're not all updated at the same time). You can even specify that you only want a single role within the deployment to be updated (helpful if, say, you have a worker role in addition to your web role, and want to leave all the worker role instances running).

when the code update happens, the VMs aren't replaced, but they *are* recycled, and when they start back up, they are running the updated code.

Comment: Thanks for this. At present I right click on the Cloud project in VS2012. A popup appears telling me that the cloud service is in use, and do I want to replace it. So I click yes, and then about 10 mins later I get completion. So perhaps I am doing an update already, or nearest to it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use WebDeploy with Cloud Services in production across multiple servers using the [AzureWebFarm](https://github.com/MRCollective/AzureWebFarm) project (disclaimer: I maintain it).

Alternatively, you can also use the excellent Octopus Deploy deployment technology in conjunction with the [AzureWebFarm.OctopusDeploy](https://github.com/MRCollective/AzureWebFarm.OctopusDeploy) project (disclaimer: I maintain this one too).

To be honest though, if you just have a simple web app then I wouldn't both with cloud services - I'd just use [Web Sites](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/web-sites/). Feel free to check out my blog post to see the situations which might force you to use cloud services though.

Comment: Hi Robert, Interesting comment. I was forced to use Cloud services as my PDF component uses GDI calls, and these are prevented in WAWS. It is a problem for many, if not all, report producing 3rd party server components. Not sure if this is linked to Full Trust, but MS has no intention of allowing GDI native calls in WAWS. However this code does work on DiscountASP shared ASP.NET hosting. So slightly puzzled by this. Therefore I think it may be a GDI restriction thing. However I do love WAWS.

Comment: Yep - GDI is unfortunately one of the things that doesn't work on web sites :(

Answer (score 1):

If you enable WebDeploy on the cloud service, you can use web deploy to publish the MVC application.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff683672.aspx for details.

Comment: Good point, but... Web deploy is only useful in dev/test, as it's limited to single-instance.

Comment: Interesting point about Web Deploy being limited to Single Instance

Answer (score 1):

All of the above answers are correct and if you are trying to change your code for a production service you definitely want to do an in place upgrade as described.  However, frequently during the dev/test phase or troubleshooting I want to make one small change and test it out quickly.  To do this check out http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/09/05/how-to-modify-a-running-azure-service.aspx which describes how to modify the code via RDP to the Azure VM.